# Assign item to item number using an associative array

Tags: perl, hash, associative-array

My goal is to associate each item with it's corresponding item number. My input file is extensive but in short looks like this:

```
678794:T.V, Samsung 
530871:iPad, Apple   #etc...
```

I'm receiving an error stating:

```
Global symbol "$items" requires explicit package name at ./items.pl line 10.

Global symbol "%item" requires explicit package name at ./items.pl line 10.
```

---

```
open (NAMES, 'items.txt') || die "Cant open it $!";

while (<NAMES>) {
    my %items;
    my $maxStrLength = "";
    (my $modelNO, my $item) = split(':',$_);
            $items = $item{$modelNO};
    if(length($item) > $maxStrLength) {
            $maxStrLength=length($item);
    }
}
close NAMES;
exit (0);
```

Comment: what is exact error message? can you describe what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Global symbol "%item" requires explicit package name at ./items.pl
I'm trying to get rid of the colons and then link each item to its corresponding number, i'm gonna print out a sorted report later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you have `use strict;` in your code.  Then you need to declare your hash with `my`:

```
my %item;
```

I recommend changing your hash name to `%items` so as not to be confused with your scalar `$item`.

Also, you should not use `my` in your `if` statement like that.  You probably want `$maxStrLength` declared outside of the while loop.

I think this is closer to what you want (self-contained runnable code):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $maxStrLength = 0;
my %items;
while (<DATA>) {
   my ($modelNO, $item) = split /:/;
   $items{$modelNO} = $item;

   if(length($item)>$maxStrLength) {
     $maxStrLength=length($item);
   }
}

__DATA__
678794:T.V, Samsung 
530871:iPad, Apple
```